# RichEdit control: Determine when text is changed?

Tags: richedit

I'm trying to count the number of times that text is changed in a given RichEdit control. I considered using events like key down, but that gets messy when you consider keys that don't change the text (like arrows, page up, etc). And how do you make sure you get all of those keys?

It seems it would be simpler to register a callback for a `onTextChanged` event, if one exists. Is there any way to do something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to listen to the EN_CHANGE message if your using C++. Note that you also have to call SetEventMask with ENM_CHANGE to receive these notifications unlike a normal edit control will sends these messages by default.